# data from listbox to form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need some help with a script. 
I have a form with a listbox and some textboxes. When i select an entry of the listbox the matching data will be displayed in that textboxes. Now i want to search through the listbox with the help of another textfield.

I created a script that is searching through my listfield and marks the matching entry.

```
For i = 0 To Me!lstPlanung.ListCount - 1

             If Me!lstPlanung.Column(0, i) Like "*" & Me!sidSuche2.Text & "*" Then

                 Me!lstPlanung.Selected(i) = True
                 Exit For

             End If

         Next i
```

But my problem is that the entry is highlited and not really selected and the data is not displayed in my textboxes until i click on the highlited entry with the mouse. Is there any way to solve this little problem?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to call the after update procedure for the list box

```
 Me!lstPlanung.Selected(i) = True
 Call lstPlanung_AfterUpdate()
             Exit For
```

This will then fire the event as if you had clicked it. You may need to make the After Update sub public.

Comment: I dont know what you mean with 'Call lstPlanung_AfterUpdate()'. I have no sub called lstPlanung.

Comment: You must have some code/macro in the After_Update event on the list box, or a command button that fills out your text boxes. However you are populating the text boxes , that is what you need to call / run.

Comment: Sorry but i dont get it. I have a macro that displays the data from the listbox in my textfields on after_update()`. The macro looks like this: =`"[SID] = " & "'" & [Screen].[ActiveControl] & "'"` .

Comment: When you set a value of a control using VBA other events are not triggered So you have to force them to fire. Hence you would need to run the macro you normally run if you manually clicked on the list box.